# wsq decoding error: WARNING: A code in the hufftable contains an all 1's code

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read and process wsq images in a machine learning application in Python. I downloaded and installed the wsq library from PyPI and was able to open and show an image using jupyter-notebook. I can also read and convert the images to pgm's using a C/C++ program. However, using Python 3.9 in PyCharm, I'm getting the following error for every image I attempt to load:

```
WARNING: A code in the hufftable contains an all 1's code.
     This image may still be decodable.
     It is not compliant with the WSQ specification.
     hufftable_id = 0
```

Relevant code:

```
import wsq
from matplotlib import image
imageArray = image.imread(imagePath)
```

The following code on github contains the same error message:

https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD/blob/master/wsq_imageio/src/org/jnbis/WSQEncoder.java

That's Java. I don't know if the wsq decoder on PyPI is written in Java or some other language.

At any rate, I can't seem to get past the error. I'd like to avoid having to convert all the images to pgm's because pgm's are much bigger and take much longer to load. Data access times are already a bottleneck.

Any ideas?

Comment: What generates those wsq images? Are you able to, say, convert them to pgm and back to wsq using a compliant encoder?

Comment: @Selcuk, I received the images as wsq's, but I like your idea of converting them to pgm and back if possible.